# Join to only work if a record present in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables - table1 and table2.

In table2, there are multiple records matching criteria for table1 based on:

c_type, h_level, loop, e_id

I want records from RIGHT table ONLY if there is EXACT 1 match. If not, element_nm should be NULL, so I have the exact same records in the output as left table.

```
SELECT   a.*,
         b.element_nm
FROM     table1 a
   LEFT JOIN table2 b ON
         a.c_type = b.c_type
   AND   a.h_level = b.h_level
   AND   a.loop = b.loop
   AND   a.e_id = b.e_id
ORDER BY a.file_name,
         a.line_num asc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is about one value only, you can use a Sub query in the select clause. Otherwise you'd use a subquery in a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or use `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  (
    SELECT MIN(t2.element_nm)
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.c_type = t1.c_type
      AND t2.h_level = t1.h_level
      AND t2.loop = t1.loop
      AND t2.e_id = t1.e_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  ) AS element_nm
FROM table1 t1
ORDER BY t1.file_name, t1.line_num;
```

Comment: I don't want minimum. If there are multiple entries in table2 for the criteria, then element_nm should be NULL. Is that possible?

Comment: There is a `HAVING` clause making sure that you get the minimum only when there is exactly one match. And in that case the minimum is equal to the maximum and equal to the sum and equal to the average … well, it's just one value. In the other case when there are multiple matches, the subquery returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Thorsten's answer works when you want only one column from the second table.  But if you want multiple columns, it is a bit cumbersome.

Alternatively:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.c_type, b.h_level, b.loop, b.e_id) as cnt
      FROM b
     ) b
     ON a.c_type = b.c_type AND
        a.h_level = b.h_level AND
        a.loop = b.loop AND
        a.e_id = b.e_id AND
        b.cnt = 1
ORDER BY a.file_name, a.line_num asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use Row_Number , like this :

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.c_type ,a.h_level,a.loop  ,a.e_id   ) rnum
 ,a.c_type ,a.h_level,a.loop  ,a.e_id FROM     table1 a
   LEFT JOIN table2 b ON  a.c_type = b.c_type  AND  a.h_level = b.h_level  AND a.loop = b.loop AND a.e_id = b.e_id
) 
,cte2 AS (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnum = 2)
         SELECT   a.*,
  CASE WHEN cte2.element_nm IS NULL then       b.element_nm ELSE NULL END element_nm
FROM     table1 a
   LEFT JOIN table2 b ON  a.c_type = b.c_type  AND  a.h_level = b.h_level  AND a.loop = b.loop AND a.e_id = b.e_id
   LEFT JOIN cte2 ON    a.c_type = cte2.c_type AND  a.h_level = cte2.h_level AND a.loop = cte2.loop AND a.e_id = cte2.e_id
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way?

Comment: or use it :;WITH a AS (SELECT * FROM table1)
,b as (SELECT * FROM table2)
,c AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.c_type ,a.h_level,a.loop  ,a.e_id ORDER BY a.c_type ,a.h_level,a.loop  ,a.e_id)RNO ,a.* 
FROM a JOIN b ON a.c_type = b.c_type  AND  a.h_level = b.h_level  AND a.loop = b.loop AND a.e_id = b.e_id )
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT c.ParentId FROM c
GROUP BY c.ParentId
HAVING COUNT(*)=1) X ON a.c_type = x.c_type  AND  a.h_level = x.h_level  AND a.loop = x.loop AND a.e_id = x.e_id